# How to find out the number of edges, faces, vertices in a polygon

Tags: java, math

Is there an easy way to find the number of edges, faces and vertices in a [polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) (say decagon or hendecagon). Is this data available as part of a java library or should it be manually derived from the wiki data.

Comment: Are you asking a purely math question, or you want to implment this?

Comment: Polygons don't have faces. Did you mean polyhedra?

Comment: I am looking for a java function which already provides this information or would like to implement it.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A function that takes a string (e.g. "triangle") and returns the number of vertices?

Comment: @Henrik - Yes, that's pretty much the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really do mean polygons rather than polyhedrons, then:

- polygons don't have faces, and
- the number of edges of a polygon is the same as the number of vertices.

If you want Java code to translate the *name* of a polygon to the number of edges or vertices, then a simple lookup table should cover all cases that you are likely to encounter.  If that is not sufficient, then the problem is pretty much the same as the problem of translating ancient greek numbers (in anglicized form) into integers.

[This page](http://phrontistery.info/numbers.html) explains how to count in anglicized ancient greek and latin, but it fizzles out at around 20.  At that point, you probably need to extemporize; i.e. make them up.

The page explain that usage beyond dodeca- is extremely rare (apart from icosahedron).  However, I'm sure you could find a few loons out there who would *love* to waste hours of your timing debating the correct name for a 42 sided polygon.

Comment: eh? polyhedrons don't have the same number of edges and verties e.g. cubes have 8 vertices and 12 edges

Comment: @Stephen C: I think you mean "polygons" in your second bullet point, not "polyhedrons". I cannot, off-hand, think of a polyhedron with the same number of vertices as edges (I can, however, think of one with the same number of faces as vertices).

Comment: The one an only correct name for a 42 sided polygon is 42-gon. In fact, triangle and square are sort of grandfathered in, but after that it's n-gon all the way.

Comment: Ah ... a loon has arrived :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be fishing for Euler's result for connected graphs:

R + N = E + 2
i.e. regions + nodes = edges + 2

You can consider this a graph on the 2D plane.

However, you can also apply it equally to polyhedra: you could wrap your graph around a ball,  and make the arcs straighten out, in which case you would want to think of 'faces' instead of 'regions'.    Topologically it's the same thing.

I always need to do a quick check to see if I got that the right way round: 
A cube has 6 faces, 8 nodes, 12 edges.  6 + 8 = 12 + 2.  Yep.  Check.  R + N = E + 2